# Angularjs ng-Repat how to remove Extension from the name

Tags: angularjs

```
   <tr ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
<td>
   <input type="text" ng-bind="item.file.name" value="{{item.file.name}}"> </td>
```

Here my file.name is **Abc.pdf** then how can i remove **.pdf** from the name

Comment: Define "not working". Post a **complete** minimal example as a plunkr, tell precisely what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: you can use a filter to pop the extension

Comment: @mehulmpt Could u please Excplain me or If u have any url plz Ping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom filter:

```
app.filter('removeExt', function () {
  return function (item) {
    var items = item.split('.')
    items.pop()
    return items.join('.')
  }
})
```

and then use

```
{{ item.file.name | removeExt }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much  You Reduce my lot of Pressure

Answer (score 0):

You can just use plain javascript, like this:

```
var file = item.file.name;
var fileName = file.split(".");
```

The split method will create an array of substrings so fileName[0] = "Abc" and fileName[1] = "pdf".